# Formatting C# output

Tags: c#, formatting

I am trying to format some c# output so that a number always has 2 digits for instance if `int = 0` i would like `Console.WriteLine(int);` to produce 00.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

This should do what you want:

```
        int num = 10;

        Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("0#"));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

The string that is passed to the ToString method "0#" has the following meaning:

```
0 - 0 place holder, this will be replaced with relevant digit if one exists
# - digit place holder.
```

So if num is 0, 00 will be written to the console but if num is 10, 10 will be written to the console.

Answer (score 5):

`for` example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
       Console.WriteLine("{0:00}", i);    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this page](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/), esp. the "Custom number formatting" section.

To show a number as two digits only you'd do something like this:

```
int x = 2;
string output = string.Format("{0:00}", x);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: +1 for using string.Format instead of Console.WriteLine (more general solution)